# Subscribing to a podcast in iTunes 11 from the URL

Tags: macos, itunes, podcasts

In previous versions of iTunes, you could go to Advanced » Subscribe to Podcast and then enter the URL.  I used this all the time.  In iTunes 11 I can't find anything comparable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command moved into the *File* menu ([source](http://forums.ilounge.com/itunes-mac-pc/276778-adding-outside-podcasts-into-itunes-podcasts.html#post1429154)).

You should be able to find it by typing `Subscribe` into the *Help* menu search text field.

[image]

Comment: wow, that makes even less sense than before...